# Updating a table with identical columns from another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to copy the column 'REGEX_MIN_DATE' from one table to another, matching on another column, 'MSCAD_ID'. Both tables have these columns. Why does the following code fail?

```
UPDATE dbo.std_cyber_mscad_cases
SET REGEX_MIN_DATE = dbo.temp_min_dates.REGEX_MIN_DATE

WHERE MSCAD_ID = dbo.temp_min_dates.MSCAD_ID
```

I'm getting the error 'The multi-part identifier "dbo.temp_min_dates.MSCAD_ID" could not be bound.'

Comment: It fails because of syntax error. See my answer.

Comment: SQL Server [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
 SET REGEX_MIN_DATE = B.REGEX_MIN_DATE
FROM dbo.std_cyber_mscad_cases A
INNER JOIN dbo.temp_min_dates B ON A.MSCAD_ID = B.MSCAD_ID
```

Comment: Explanatory text would help. Something like *"You need to actually join the other table to be able to refer to it in the `UPDATE` query. For example:"*

Comment: @Charlieface You are totally right. I would improve my answers as you said.

Comment: Thank you both! That's done the trick - good to know where my thinking was going wrong too.

Comment: @Tim1729 Please accept the answers, if it solves the problem

Comment: Alright, I've done so!